# Calculate area between circle and corner (≠ 90°)

Tags: geometry

I want to calculate the area in yellow as a function of the angle $\alpha$. As $\alpha$ approaches $90^\circ$, the area should become infinite. Conversely, when $\alpha$ approaches $0$, so does the yellow area. But what is the formula?

[image]

Comment: First of all, the yellow area approaches infinity as A approaches 180. Not 90.

Comment: I have tried to calculate the area of the triangle AOB as a function of r, but then I cannot find the distance AB so I am stuck. I have tried using the height BE, but same problem with AD. We know that BE=AB*r/AO, and using Pythagoras and trigonometry, I always end up with more unknows than knowns...:-/

Comment: I think that it approaches infinity when alpha reaches 90, of if you will when 2*alpha is 180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Area of a circular sector or radius $r$ and angle $\alpha$:
   $$A = \pi r^2\ \frac{\alpha}{2\pi} = \frac{\alpha r^2}{2}.$$
2. Area of a rectangular triangle given the length $l$ of one of the cathetus and the angle between that side and the hypotenuse $\alpha$:
   $$A = \frac{l^2}{2}\ \tan{\alpha}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Find the area of triangle AOB. *I would use the tangent function.*

Then find the area of the sector of the circle from B to D.

Then subtract the areas.